# Breeze data types for binary array

Tags: breeze

I have a Breeze server entity that contains a binary[] type, using EF/SQLServer. I have the field type on the client side initialized as new ArrayBuffer() using createEntity on the entity manager. I am stuffing an ArrayBuffer object into that field; upon Save, the server side gets an object reference not set to instance of an object. The server side error looks like it is attempting a JsonReader.IsWrappedInTypeObject() at JsonReader.ReadAsBytes(), etc. It seems like that should work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer: I used the HTML5 FileReader and readAsDataURL; then I parsed the resulting type and base64string into my entity fields. The base64string maps nicely into the byte[] on the server side.